# Error on Implementing Kruskal´s Minimal Spanning Tree in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, kruskals-algorithm

i tried to implement Kruskal´s Minimal Spanning Tree in Java. I´m using Eclipse for writing.
I used this website (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-algorithm-greedy-algo-2/) to get started and changed the Code with german commands and my own, bigger example.

Here is my Code:

```
package Kruskal_Algorithmus;

//Java-Programm für den Kruskal Algorithmus
//Ziel ist es einen minimalen Spannbaum aus einem gegebenen zusammenhängenden, ungerichteten, endlichen
//und kantengewichteten Graphen zu erzeugen.

import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 

class Graph 
{ 
    // Erstellung einer Klasse zur Erzeugung einer neuen Kante im Graphen 
    class Kante implements Comparable<Kante> 
    { 
        int quelle, richtung, gewicht; 

        // Erzeugung einer Vergleichs-Funktion damit eine Sortierung der gegeben Kanten
        // nach ihrem Gewicht / Kosten möglich ist
        public int compareTo(Kante kantenVergleich) 
        { 
            return this.gewicht-kantenVergleich.gewicht; 
        } 
    }; 


    // Erstellung einer Klasse um Teilmenge mit Hilfe von Union-Find zu finden
    class subset 
    { 
        int parent, rank; 
    }; 



    int K, E; // K => Anzahl der Knoten & E => Anzahl der Kanten 
    Kante kante[]; // Zusammenfassung aller Kanten im Kanten-Array 

    // Graph mit K Knoten und E (edge) Kanten wird erstellt
    Graph(int k, int e) 
    { 
        K = k; 
        E = e; 
        kante = new Kante[E]; 
        for (int i=0; i<e; ++i) 
            kante[i] = new Kante(); 
    } 

    // Erstellung einer Funktion die eine gewünschte Teilmenge aus den Elemente i heraus sucht
    // (Anwendung von "Path compression")
    int find(subset teilmengen[], int i) 
    { 
        // Suche und vergabe der Eltern-Teilmenge (parent) 
        if (teilmengen[i].parent != i) 
            teilmengen[i].parent = find(teilmengen, teilmengen[i].parent); 

        return teilmengen[i].parent; 
    } 

    // Eine Funktion die die Teilmengen x und y vereint und das Array subsets bildet
    void Union(subset subsets[], int x, int y) 
    { 
        int xroot = find(subsets, x); 
        int yroot = find(subsets, y); 

        // Teilbäume werden nach ihrem Rang in der Sortierung geordnet
        if (subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank) 
            subsets[xroot].parent = yroot; 
        else if (subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank) 
            subsets[yroot].parent = xroot; 

        // Falls zwei Mal der selbe Rang auftaucht wird ein Element einen Rang weiter nach unten geschoben
        else
        { 
            subsets[yroot].parent = xroot; 
            subsets[xroot].rank++; 
        } 
    } 

    // Funktion zur Erstellung des Minimal Spanning Tree nach Kruskal
    void KruskalMST() 
    { 
        Kante ergebnis[] = new Kante[K]; // hier wird finaler MST gespeichert
        int e = 0; // Index-Variable, welche für das Ergebnis-Array benötigt wird 
        int i = 0; // Index-Variable welche für die sortierten Kanten benötigt wird
        for (i=0; i<K; ++i) 
            ergebnis[i] = new Kante(); 

        // Schritt 1: Alle Kanten werden in nicht absteigender Reihenfolge nach ihrem 
        // Gewicht / ihren Kosten sortiert.
        // Da gegebener Graph ggf. nicht zu ändern ist, erstellen wir eine Kopie
        // des Kanten-Arrays.
        Arrays.sort(kante); 

        // Zuweisung, unter welchem Array die zu erzeugenden Teilmengen gespeichert werden
        subset subsets[] = new subset[K]; 
        for(i=0; i<K; ++i) 
            subsets[i]=new subset(); 

        // Teilmengen mit einzelnen Elementen werden erzeugt
        for (int v = 0; v < K; ++v) 
        { 
            subsets[v].parent = v; 
            subsets[v].rank = 0; 
        } 

        i = 0; // Index-Variable, welche die nächste zubearbeitende Kante auswählt 

        // Ziel: Kantenmenge des MSP = Knotenanzahl - 1 
        while (e < K - 1) 
        { 
            // Schritt 2: Kante mit geringsten Kosten wird ausgewählt.
            // Index-Variable wird für nächste Wiederholung um 1 erhöht.
            Kante next_edge = new Kante(); 
            next_edge = kante[i++]; 

            int x = find(subsets, next_edge.quelle); 
            int y = find(subsets, next_edge.richtung); 

            // Wenn das hinzufügen der Kante in den MST keinen Kreis / Zyklus ergibt,
            // wird Kante zur Lösung hinzugefügt und Variable des Lösungs-Index um 1 erhöht.

            if (x != y) 
            { 
                ergebnis[e++] = next_edge; 
                Union(subsets, x, y); 
            } 
            // Falls es doch zu einem Kreis kommt, wird die ausgewählte Kante verworfen.
        } 

        // Ergebnisse werden mithilfe des Ergebnis-Arrays auf der Konsole ausgegeben.
        // Der fertige MST ist erkennbar. 
        System.out.println("Der gesuchte Minimal Spanning Tree wird folgendermaßen aufgebaut:"); 
        for (i = 0; i < e; ++i) 
            System.out.println(ergebnis[i].quelle+" -> " + 
                ergebnis[i].richtung+" Gewicht: " + ergebnis[i].gewicht); 
    } 

    // ausführbares Programm: 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 

        //gegebener Graph wird im Programm erstellt:

        int knotenAnzahl = 12; // Anzahl der Knoten im gegebenen Graphen 
        int kantenAnzahl = 66; // Anzahl der Kanten im gegebenen Graphen
        Graph graph = new Graph(knotenAnzahl, kantenAnzahl); 

        // Kante 1 -> 2
        graph.kante[0].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[0].richtung = 2; 
        graph.kante[0].gewicht = 32; 

        // Kante 1 -> 3 
        graph.kante[1].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[1].richtung = 3; 
        graph.kante[1].gewicht = 45; 

        // Kante 1 -> 4
        graph.kante[2].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[2].richtung = 4; 
        graph.kante[2].gewicht = 43; 

        // Kante 1 -> 5 
        graph.kante[3].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[3].richtung = 5; 
        graph.kante[3].gewicht = 28; 

        // Kante 1 -> 6 
        graph.kante[4].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[4].richtung = 6; 
        graph.kante[4].gewicht = 11; 

        // Kante 1 -> 7 
        graph.kante[5].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[5].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[5].gewicht = 16;

        // Kante 1 -> 8 
        graph.kante[6].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[6].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[6].gewicht = 28;    

        // Kante 1 -> 9 
        graph.kante[7].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[7].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[7].gewicht = 37;

        // Kante 1 -> 10 
        graph.kante[8].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[8].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[8].gewicht = 46;

        // Kante 1 -> 11
        graph.kante[9].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[9].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[9].gewicht = 8;

        // Kante 1 -> 12 
        graph.kante[10].quelle = 1; 
        graph.kante[10].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[10].gewicht = 5;

        // Kante 2 -> 3
        graph.kante[11].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[11].richtung = 3; 
        graph.kante[11].gewicht = 12;

        // Kante 2 -> 4
        graph.kante[12].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[12].richtung = 4; 
        graph.kante[12].gewicht = 16;

        // Kante 2 -> 5 
        graph.kante[13].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[13].richtung = 5; 
        graph.kante[13].gewicht = 42;

        // Kante 2 -> 6 
        graph.kante[14].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[14].richtung = 6; 
        graph.kante[14].gewicht = 36;

        // Kante 2 -> 7
        graph.kante[15].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[15].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[15].gewicht = 22;

        // Kante 2 -> 8
        graph.kante[16].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[16].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[16].gewicht = 17;

        // Kante 2 -> 9
        graph.kante[17].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[17].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[17].gewicht = 50;

        // Kante 2 -> 10
        graph.kante[18].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[18].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[18].gewicht = 33;

        // Kante 2 -> 11
        graph.kante[19].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[19].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[19].gewicht = 8;

        // Kante 2 -> 12
        graph.kante[20].quelle = 2; 
        graph.kante[20].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[20].gewicht = 2;

        // Kante 3 -> 4
        graph.kante[21].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[21].richtung = 4; 
        graph.kante[21].gewicht = 41;

        // Kante 3 -> 5
        graph.kante[22].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[22].richtung = 5; 
        graph.kante[22].gewicht = 34;

        // Kante 3 -> 6
        graph.kante[23].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[23].richtung =6; 
        graph.kante[23].gewicht = 47;

        // Kante 3 -> 7
        graph.kante[24].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[24].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[24].gewicht = 49;

        // Kante 3 -> 8
        graph.kante[25].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[25].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[25].gewicht = 46;

        // Kante 3 -> 9
        graph.kante[26].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[26].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[26].gewicht = 36;

        // Kante 3 -> 10
        graph.kante[27].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[27].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[27].gewicht = 49;

        // Kante 3 -> 11
        graph.kante[28].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[28].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[28].gewicht = 32;

        // Kante 3 -> 12
        graph.kante[29].quelle = 3; 
        graph.kante[29].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[29].gewicht = 35;

        // Kante 4 -> 5
        graph.kante[30].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[30].richtung = 5; 
        graph.kante[30].gewicht = 35;

        // Kante 4 -> 6
        graph.kante[31].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[31].richtung = 6; 
        graph.kante[31].gewicht = 42;

        // Kante 4 -> 7
        graph.kante[32].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[32].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[32].gewicht = 2;

        // Kante 4 -> 8
        graph.kante[33].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[33].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[33].gewicht = 2;

        // Kante 4 -> 9
        graph.kante[34].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[34].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[34].gewicht = 12;

        // Kante 4 -> 10
        graph.kante[35].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[35].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[35].gewicht = 47;

        // Kante 4 -> 11
        graph.kante[36].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[36].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[36].gewicht = 39;

        // Kante 4 -> 12
        graph.kante[37].quelle = 4; 
        graph.kante[37].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[37].gewicht = 15;

        // Kante 5 -> 6
        graph.kante[38].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[38].richtung = 6; 
        graph.kante[38].gewicht = 19;

        // Kante 5 -> 7
        graph.kante[39].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[39].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[39].gewicht = 20;

        // Kante 5 -> 8
        graph.kante[40].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[40].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[40].gewicht = 5;

        // Kante 5 -> 9
        graph.kante[41].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[41].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[41].gewicht = 23;

        // Kante 5 -> 10
        graph.kante[42].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[42].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[42].gewicht = 14;

        // Kante 5 -> 11
        graph.kante[43].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[43].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[43].gewicht = 9;

        // Kante 5 -> 12
        graph.kante[44].quelle = 5; 
        graph.kante[44].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[44].gewicht = 47;

        // Kante 6 -> 7
        graph.kante[45].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[45].richtung = 7; 
        graph.kante[45].gewicht = 43;

        // Kante 6 -> 8
        graph.kante[46].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[46].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[46].gewicht = 6;

        // Kante 6 -> 9
        graph.kante[47].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[47].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[47].gewicht = 24;

        // Kante 6 -> 10
        graph.kante[48].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[48].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[48].gewicht = 32;

        // Kante 6 -> 11
        graph.kante[49].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[49].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[49].gewicht = 44;

        // Kante 6 -> 12
        graph.kante[50].quelle = 6; 
        graph.kante[50].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[50].gewicht = 3;

        // Kante 7 -> 8
        graph.kante[51].quelle = 7; 
        graph.kante[51].richtung = 8; 
        graph.kante[51].gewicht = 14;

        // Kante 7 -> 9
        graph.kante[52].quelle = 7; 
        graph.kante[52].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[52].gewicht = 26;

        // Kante 7 -> 10
        graph.kante[53].quelle = 7; 
        graph.kante[53].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[53].gewicht = 39;

        // Kante 7 -> 11
        graph.kante[54].quelle = 7; 
        graph.kante[54].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[54].gewicht = 8;

        // Kante 7 -> 12
        graph.kante[55].quelle = 7; 
        graph.kante[55].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[55].gewicht = 24;

        // Kante 8 -> 9
        graph.kante[56].quelle = 8; 
        graph.kante[56].richtung = 9; 
        graph.kante[56].gewicht = 1;

        // Kante 8 -> 10
        graph.kante[57].quelle = 8; 
        graph.kante[57].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[57].gewicht = 19;

        // Kante 8 -> 11
        graph.kante[58].quelle = 8; 
        graph.kante[58].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[58].gewicht = 14;

        // Kante 8 -> 12
        graph.kante[59].quelle = 8; 
        graph.kante[59].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[59].gewicht = 39;

        // Kante 9 -> 10
        graph.kante[60].quelle = 9; 
        graph.kante[60].richtung = 10; 
        graph.kante[60].gewicht = 6;

        // Kante 9 -> 11
        graph.kante[61].quelle = 9; 
        graph.kante[61].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[61].gewicht = 47;

        // Kante 9 -> 12
        graph.kante[62].quelle = 9; 
        graph.kante[62].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[62].gewicht = 25;

        // Kante 10 -> 11
        graph.kante[63].quelle = 10; 
        graph.kante[63].richtung = 11; 
        graph.kante[63].gewicht = 15;

        // Kante 10 -> 12
        graph.kante[64].quelle = 10; 
        graph.kante[64].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[64].gewicht = 21;

        // Kante 11 -> 12
        graph.kante[65].quelle = 11; 
        graph.kante[65].richtung = 12; 
        graph.kante[65].gewicht = 11;


        graph.KruskalMST(); 
    } 
}
```

In Eclipse i get this Error Code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
    at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.find(Graph.java:53)
    at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.KruskalMST(Graph.java:117)
    at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.main(Graph.java:479)
```

I´m really new to Java Coding, and have no clue how to get this program working. I hope you have some tips for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Would you please mark line 53 of Graph.java.

Comment: Line 53 is: if (teilmengen[i].parent != i)

Comment: You should walk through this program step-by-step with a debugger until you get the error.

Comment: Or you could put a print statement at the start of find() which prints the arguments. It should become obvious what the error is. It is obvious from the error that the program is trying to access item 12 of an array (i.e., the 13th element) with only 12 items.

Answer (score 0):

Your numbering of graph nodes seems to start with 1: `1, 2, 3, ..., 12`

Array indexes in Java however start with `0`. When you create an array of 12 items, the last item has index 11. There is no array element at index 12.

You have a few options: You could change your numbering so that node number matches with array indexes. This is likely the easiest. For example what was an edge 6-12 changes to an edge 5-11.

```
    // Kante 6 -> 12
    graph.kante[50].quelle = 5; 
    graph.kante[50].richtung = 11;
```

Alternatively, subtract 1 from the node number to get the index in your loops. OR add extra space to all arrays that are indexed by graph node. For example:

```
    subset subsets[] = new subset[K + 1];
```

If you choose the last option you'll also have to change any loops that iterate on nodes. The currently iterate on 0-11 when your nodes are numbered 1-12.

```
    for(i=1; i<=K; ++i) 
        subsets[i]=new subset();
```

Comment: Good Morning, i changed the Array how you said. Now i get following error code:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.find(Graph.java:53)
 at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.KruskalMST(Graph.java:117)
 at Kruskal_Algorithmus.Graph.main(Graph.java:479)

Comment: If you go by that route you'll need to change a few more things. All your loops seen to assume the nodes are numbered 0-11.